# Minimum number of elements Enhanced for-loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am trying to run this Enhanced for-loop but it throws an error. When I increase the number of elements in the array to 8 then it works. Is there a minimum number of elements in an array for it to work?

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int numbers[];
        numbers = new int[] {5,6,7,5,5};

        for(int i : numbers){
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no minimum number of elements for it to work; you are misunderstanding what it does.  The values assigned to `i` are the values in the array, not the indices in the array, but you are treating the values as indices, and in an array of 5 elements, index `7` (or `5` or `6`) doesn't exist.  That is also why it works when you put 8 elements; index `7` now exists.

Just print `i`.  It's the value.

```
System.out.println(i);
```

You may want to consider renaming `i` to `value`, or `number`, or something more indicative of what it is, to avoid confusion, because `i` is usually used for index variables in standard `for` loops.

Comment: Maybe suggest renaming `i` to `number`, since `i` is "reserved" (by convention) for index variables, which is the cause of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Print i. Not numbers[i]
i is the  actual value not the item index in the array and there is no numbers[5] for example and this will throws Exception

Answer (score 0):

This code contains a simple logical error:

```
for(int i : numbers){ //<-- loop over all integers in numbers (i will hold the value in the array
    System.out.println(numbers[i]); //<-- get the element at position i
}
```

Basically your code would do this sequence of reads in the array:

```
numbers[5]
numbers[6]
numbers[7]
...
```

Decide whether to use a foreach-loop that directly iterates over all elements in the array (`for(int i : numbers)`) and simply print the values from the iteration (`System.out.println(i)`), or iterate over the **indices** in `[0 , numbers.length)` and use `System.out.println(numbers[i])`.

The "minimum-number" you're experiencing is simply due to the fact that 7 is the biggest number in the array and thus the the array must atleast be of length 8 in order to access `numbers[7]` without throwing any exception.